# Jersey SSE service takes long time to establish connection with Chrome browser as a client

Tags: java, rest, google-chrome, jersey-2.0, server-sent-events

I implemented Jersey SSE broadcasting service similar to the Jersey [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224105423/https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#d0e11862):

```
@GET
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput listenToBroadcast() {
    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    this.broadcaster.add(eventOutput);
    return eventOutput;
}
```

The first client connects without issues, but for all additional clients it takes at least 10 seconds to connect to the service. The delay occurs before client request reaches my code. After clients finally connects it starts to receive events normally.
There is no connection delay only if there is no already connected clients during registration.

Then using Java client the connection is established immediately, but Chrome for some reason takes a very long time to connect and start receiving messages.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

I am using Jersey 2.24, Tomcat 8.5.9 and Java 8